# What should be the first 5 feats a Barbarian picks?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, feats

We are  talking a Rageblood vigor

Con and Str based

In order - but since order can be discussed, lets not do that. Then I think most can agree on 3-4 out of 5 in others answers, so no reason to dicuss them as such, just post them.

Things to consider: Primary Role is striker, damage output is important. Survival is too.

Comment: What race are you?

Comment: oh yeah, thought that I thought it through. Wish I could let that one be open, but that could generate too many/too complex answers - love your end relust though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25175217/Appetite_for_Destruction:_The_Barbarians_Handbook), and assuming all books allowed, though you're not interested in looking at the new Beserker, I recommend.

For a dwarf:

1: Dwarven Weapon Proficiency

2: Bludgeon Expertise (You'll want this for the avalanche maul) or Enduring Mountain (tribal feats are excellent if everyone buys in)

4: Improved Defenses (your ref and will will be low. This helps a little) or Bludgeon Expertise

6: Cunning Stalker (if you're off and about charging random people away from your party) or Mark of Storm (While it doesn't support an avalanche hammer, it's doubtful that your DM will give one to you. A lightning weapon is a lot more common, and a slide 2 on hit is excellent for making enemies stick to your defender and setting up your next charge.)

8: Deadly draw (if mark of storm) or Blood Cousin's Tribe (if people've gone enduring mountain) or Reckless Charge

For a Goliath

1: Goliath Greatweapon Prowess
then, as above. Goliaths don't need superior weapons with greatweapon prowess.

For a  Half-Orc

1: Bludgeon Expertise or Heavy Blade Expertise (depending on your style and whether or not you can request a badge of the beserker)

2: Weapon Focus or Enduring Mountain

4: Toughness or Improved Defenses

6: Cunning stalker or as above

8: Thirst for Battle

For a Minotaur

As half-orc, but 8 should be bloodied ferocity

For a Warforged

As half-orc, but 6 should be warforged tactics, and 8 reckless charge or go the mark of storm route

### To generalize

Taken from the charop guide:

> 1. Accuracy bonuses - A Barbarian's attacks are dealing a lot of damage pretty much by default; a bigger priority for you is making sure those attacks actually get to connect, especially considering you don't have a native accuracy-boosting feature and you usually only get one shot at landing them.
> 2. Damage bonuses - While Barbarian attacks are pretty damaging already, it never hurts to pack more punch on your hits, you being a Striker and all.
> 3. Mobility enhancements - One of the best ways to accomplish the above two priorities is by charge optimization, since there are items to enhance accuracy and damage for chargers. Throw in some mobility to generate the necessary space to charge early and often, and you have yourself a character.
> 4. Defense bonuses - While Barbarian Agility combined with raising Strength and Dexterity aggressively should cover the majority of your defenses nicely by default, some investment in making yourself tougher to hit is certainly not a waste of time, especially on the non-AC defenses side.
> 5. Miscellaneous - After those basic tenets are covered, you pretty much have free rein with any feat slots you may have left over. I personally prefer to optimize initiative (and thus get my blows in faster) or power recovery (to get another go at using good powers) of, if you have the room, both.

For a strcon barb, especially one with a non-trivial investment into con, you'll be really hurting. Your first feat, however, should almost always be iconic or accuracy-related. +1 and a bennie is the best way to inflict the best status condition there is: dead. However, before accuracy is the signature weapon of the barbarian. As a charger, you functionally have 2 enchantments to choose from in the heroic tier: Vanguard (+1d8 damage while charging)  works on any melee, but a fullblade is your best bet for the increased accuracy. Whiffing a howling strike sucks. Or Avalanche Hammer Mordenkrad, for a lovely +1[W] on charging. With an avalanche mordenkrad, your charger will be doing 5d6 (+1d6 because horned helm) brutal 1... at will. It's therefore important to choose between weapon types as early as possible.

If you were a strdex barb (very much recommended, You don't need a secondary con to take advantage of rageblood) I would instead recommend a vanguard gouge, so you can take advantage of a fighter multiclass for surprsing charge and spear expertise. +scaling to damage from the expertise,+1[W] with surprising charge with combat advantage (gained from cunning stalker) makes you ... remarkably scary.

If you want your DM to throw dice at you, I recommend mounted combat and a dire boar. Dice *will* be thrown, however.

Enduring Mountain is something I've got experience with in my own games. It grants a remarkable amount of health per surge used if everyone buys in and helps make up for a lackluster leader. Or for the depressing healing demands an almost naked strcon barb imposes.

Improved defenses is generic, but useful. When you have slots open up, it's worth retraining into superior X (or just grabbing superior will on top of it.) Grabbing superior reflexes is also nice on the combat advantage charging chassis for that excellent first-round combat advantage.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that Lances give +1[W] while mounted and charging, and counts as a spear.

Comment: ... ::whimper::

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my books in front of me now but I think a Human Barbarian/Seeker Hybrid. Now before you fail this idea, think about what I am about to say.

**Bonus Feat:** Hybrid Talent (Seeker's Bond) - Now you add your strength to your AC and you can throw heavy weapons, which returns back to you freely.

**Feat 1:** Hybrid Talent (Barbarian Agility) - Add +3 to AC. Now your a hard hitter with good defense and accuracy.

**Feat 2:** Hybrid Talent (Bloodrage vigor) - Now you gain CON THP for each attack you hit.

**Feat 3:** Improved Missiles - Now anything you throw +2 Atk! So you can mix up your fighting styles plus you can reach anything and you have distance in a tough fight. Now immobile isn't your achilie's heel.

**Feat 4:** Multiclass Ranger - You get two-weapon defense. +1 AC and Ref.

**Feat 5:** Novice swap - Swap out one daily for Spitting Cobra Stance. While in this stance, anyone 5 squares away can provoke ranged OA from you.

**Note:** After looking this over, Bloodrage Vigor may no be a good feat because you don't have to stay in the thick of battle. But that is up to you.

Comment: While this is a fascinating build (really quite fascinating...) it doesn't fit a str/con rageblood barb. -1 for off topic. On the other hand, I encourage you to submit it as an answer to a question of "interesting hybrid characters" which... should probably be asked.

Comment: Hey, no fair. I met the parameters. Str and Con all went into the feat listing. Focused on Striking and survivability. I only made a suggestion at the end to give the guy some more options just in case. Just because it's doesn't look like a traditional build doesn't mean i went off topic.

Comment: Er, you made it a *hybrid* mate. :) But as a striker hybrid, it's fascinating. It's just not a rageblood barb. (I also have some reservations of a hurler barb, but there are some interesting builds that can support that.) Also, two-weapon is far more whirling than rageblood. Still, I'd absolutely upvote this for a question on hybrids.